# Why does an imaginary increment allows us to differentiate?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

For example, Take $$(x+i\Delta x)^2-x^2\over i\Delta x$$
It yields:$$2x+i\Delta x$$
By taking the real part of the answer we get:$$2x$$
Which what we expected if we took the Limit !!
Why does this method give us a correct answer? 
Is this only for polynomials or does this work with transcendental functions? 
If not is there a counter example? 
If it IS correct, can it be used to DEFINE  the derivative?

Comment: Hint: Try with $x \mapsto x^3$. Can you figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I mean, instead of trying your definition on the function $x \mapsto x^2$, try it on the function $x \mapsto x^3$ and study the difference to your example. (EDIT: OP removed his comment asking for a clarification of the previous comment.)

Comment: oh I see. It generates real parts as we have $i^2=-1$ and we get real results again.which collapses our method.

Comment: Correct. In your example you just got lucky with the right parts cancelling each other out.